# Fourier series expansion

Tags: fourier-analysis

I know that Fourier series for f(x) is
$$f(x)=A_o+\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty} (A_n cos(n\pi x/L)+B_n sin(n\pi x/L) ) $$
where 
$$A_o=\frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) dx$$
$$A_n=\frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) cos(n\pi x/L)dx$$ 
$$B_n=\frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) sin(n\pi x/L)dx$$
But sometimes I found problems solved using integration from 0 to 2L instead of integration from -L to L :
$$A_o=\frac{1}{2L} \int_{0}^{2L} f(x) dx$$
$$A_n=\frac{1}{L} \int_{0}^{2L} f(x) cos(n\pi x/L)dx$$ 
$$B_n=\frac{1}{L} \int_{0}^{2L} f(x) sin(n\pi x/L)dx$$
**My question is : when to use integration from -L to L and when to use intergration from 0 to 2L?**

For example : the following problem ( in polar coordinates )
Find the temperature u inside a circular disk $$0\leq r\leq a$$ if it is governed by
$$\nabla^2u=0$$  i.e. $$u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r} u_r + \frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta\theta}=0$$
given that 
$$ u(a,\theta)= f(\theta)=2 \pi \theta - \theta^2$$

I solved this problem and I fot finally that 
$$f(\theta)=A_o+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a^n A_n cos(n\theta)+a^n B_n sin(n\theta))$$
then if I used  $$A_o=\frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) dx$$ I got $$A_o=\frac{\pi^2}{3}$$
But if I used $$A_o=\frac{1}{2L} \int_{0}^{2L} f(x) dx$$ I got $$A_o=\frac{2 \pi^2}{3}$$

where $$L=\pi\  Since\  u \  is \  periodic\  with\ 2\pi \  and \ L \ is \ half \ of \ the\  period.$$

Comment: Once you extend the function you're expanding to be periodic with period $2L$ on all of $\mathbb{R}$, then you can use any interval of length $2L$ that you want in order to compute the coefficients, and to use for the expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, in the example above, you are modelling a function in terms of 'basis' functions $x\mapsto 1, x \mapsto \cos {n \pi x \over L}, x \mapsto \sin {n \pi x \over L}$, so the resulting function must be $2L$ periodic.

If $f$, the function being modelled, is $2L$ periodic, then it clearly does not matter what particular interval you take, as long as it is $2L$ long.

However, you may be interested in modelling a function that is **not** $2L$ periodic, but over an interval that is $2L$ long. One way is to define a $2L$
periodic $g$ that matches $f$ on the interval of interest (there may be a
discontinuity at the end points, but this often doesn't matter in applications) and then, as above, any interval of length $2L$ will do.

However, rather than going through the process of defining such a $g$, we just integrate over the interval of interest, which amounts to the same thing.

So, when the integration is over $[-L,L]$ then we are interested in modelling
$f$ on $[-L,L]$, and similarly for $[0,2L]$, mutatis mutandis.

There is another technique which can be used to model $f$ that represents $f$
in terms of $\cos, \sin$. If we are interested in $f$ over the interval
$[0,L]$ instead, we can extend $f$ so that it is even on $[-L,L]$ and then
the Fourier series will only contain constant and $\cos $ terms (but the
modelling is only valid over $[0,L]$, of course). By extending $f$ to be odd on
$[-L,L]$ (this may introduce a discontinuity at $x=0$), we can model $f$
on $[0,L]$ in terms of $\sin$ terms.

The point of the latter paragraph is that when we compute the $A_n$ (when
$f$ is extended to be even) we compute
$A_n=\frac{2}{L} \int_{0}^{L} f(x) \cos{n\pi x \over L}dx $, and
similarly for $A_0$, and we know that $B_n = 0$. Again, if we extend $f$
to be odd, we have
$B_n=\frac{2}{L} \int_{0}^{L} f(x) \sin{n\pi x \over L}dx $.